# get data from dynamic generated url

Tags: php

I have list of data in

[List Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knamm.png)

Now when i click on more then I pass that particular row data to another page like engine.html using post. In engine.html I use javascript to change link using

```
history.replaceState( {} , "engine", "' . $_POST['link'] . '" );
```

in this $_POST['link'] is generated dynamic link using passed data the link is

> yamaha-st-l-4.30-p-2963-656.html

it is working fine in my system when i click on more. it give me 
[Detail Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIm9B.png)

but when I copy this link and paste in new tab then it give me error

to check error please refer this link

[error link](http://202.131.106.60/marine/yamaha-st-l-4.30-p-2963-656.html)

i want detail page in other tab also with dynamic data..

Please Help Me..

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us _what_ error you get! What message, what do you see, where does that error occur...

Comment: please check the given link..

Comment: No, everything that's needed to answer the question must be in the question. See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/476)

Comment: Please note that the recommendations for how to phrase a question _clearly_ state that _all_ information has to be included inline in the question itself. Links to off site resources are not a replacement for that.

Comment: i have updated question please help me

Comment: So, you will need to make your web server return some useful site when you request the URL `yamaha-st-l-4.30-p-2963-656.html` from it. That's a bit broad for us to explain to you how to do that…

Comment: no..i just want my dynamic data when i open this url in other system..Last 656 is my row data dynamic id..using this id i want that row data in other system..i want to pass this id with post or get method to engin.html page.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:

yamaha-st-l-4.30-p-2963-656.html is not a link but rather the name of an HTML file. You may use that file name to create a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp), i.e. an HTML link with the <a> tag, as follows:

```
<a href="yamaha-st-l-4.30-p-2963-656.html">read more</a>
```

The <a> tag has an href (hypertext reference) attribute which in this case is using a *relative* URL, i.e. the other parts of the URL default to  those of the current page.

The fact that the file could not be located when the relative URL was pasted into a browser tab, indicates that in this particular case the necessity of the other parts of the URL, namely the scheme which indicates the file transfer protocol, which may be HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP,  etc. You also need to indicate the hostname, typically something in the form of **www.example.com** unless on a local webserver where it is *localhost*.  Lastly, you may need to indicate the full path to the file which may include one or more subdirectories aka file folders.
Read more about the URL [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

Now if there were an issue after pasting the full URL into a browser tab, then one would need to inspect whether the file might have been removed or renamed.